# Socket Io - send image data to other sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm build a chat application where users can message and send images in real time using socket.io. Currently, whenever  a user sends a messages, a `POST` request is made to the server soley to upload the image to my Node server. Once this has completed, the `uploaded image url` is returned and is sent using `socket.emit` to the recipient. The recipient receives the uploaded image url and displays it.

The problem I am having is that there is a **small delay** when trying to load images hosted on my node server. This delay is evident when users receieve messages in real time and causes **bad ux**

An alternative to this would be to send messages (in real time) using a format such as `BLOB` or `Buffer`. The message would be saved in the background to the database. Images send are typically between `40-50mb`, however could vary.

Which solution is recommended, and is there any drawbacks of using the second method? Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, this problem has 2 solutions:

First you need to wait and when the photo is uploaded, then send the message and photo address together to the recipient(actually after upload response). To solve the ux problem, with this solution, you can put a loading so that the user will know that , needs to wait a little while  upload a photo.

Second, send the message and when the photo upload process is finished, send the uploaded image url to the recipient via signalR.